# Python3: Get keyboard input without effect from cursor blink rate

Tags: python, input, keyboard, real-time

I am trying to find some sort of library or function so I can get fast keyboard input.

Right now, using the Conio.h input method, you can hold down a key, but you have to wait a half a second for it to start repeating, the same as in any text box. This seems to be dictated by the cursor repeat delay, shown here.

[image: Cursor blink rate]

Any way to get realtime keyboard input rather than having to suffer this small delay?

I've heard of pyHook but that doesn't work for Python 3(.2). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually wrote a small DLL to use the Win32 function `GetAsyncKeyState`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do it the hard way, creating your own window and then listening for keydown and keyup events, using a timer to trigger the "repeat" of the keypress.

Comment: Eventually, I wrote a Pascal DLL to use GetAsyncKeyState rather than setting up a window and stuff.